# Change place navigation button

Tags: iphone, backbarbuttonitem

How to change place navigationBack button with another button?

I wrote something like:

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: editButton, self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem , nil]; 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = arr;
```

and I want to navigationButton after editButton.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? Do you want to have a navigation Back button? Do you want another button in place of it?

Comment: I want to have on the first place edit button and next BackButton

Comment: So you want multiple buttons on the UINavigationBar

Comment: So you want 2 buttons on the left. Correct?

Comment: Yes, this code in my post insert two button on the left side but not properly position (first back second edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have edit  button on the right and on on the left it will be default back button

for edit button on the right write this code in view did load

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(edit)];
```

Then you should take one view with both these buttons on it and add this view on navigation bar

Comment: I know how to insert button on the right side, but I want to put buttons on the left side in correct order (edit and next back)